# Working of ring modulator

Tags: communication, modulation, digital-modulation

I am having trouble understanding how this ring modulator works i.e. how it multiplies the input & carrier to give us appropriate output? Any help or guide will bedeeply appreciated.
[image: Reference - Wikipedia] Reference - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_modulation

Comment: Have you tried reading your linked article's text?

Comment: Yes I have gone through the explaination they give there but to my mind it's not clear how the bridge is causing the two signals to get multiplied - also, the theory there says that for this part of cycle this is on & so on... but how excatly voltages are getting multiplied - this I AM NOT able to concieve.

Comment: They're kind of cheating when they say "multiply" without explaining that when a diode is switched OFF and is, therefore, blocking a signal, that's equivalent to multiplying the signal by zero, and when it's switched ON and the signal is allowed to pass, that's equivalent to multiplying the signal by 1.

Answer (score 2):

The use of "multiply" in this instance refers to that when a diode is switched OFF and is, therefore, blocking a signal, that's equivalent to multiplying the signal by zero, and when it's switched ON and the signal is allowed to pass, that's equivalent to multiplying the signal by 1.

Comment: Oh! is it that? I thought that two signals are getting algebrically multiplied. Anyway can you give some reference from where I can read how to multiply two signals as it actually happens in amplitude modulation. Thanx!

Comment: @Madhusudana: Sure. Try [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation)